# Error handling ñ in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am writing a script that reads a csv file and uses the pandas library to create a pivot table.

I keep receiving an error ('utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 6: invalid continuation byte) that I have linked back to the use of 'ñ' in one of the names in the csv file.

I have searched for hours trying to find a way to handle this. I have tried including the encoding type in my pandas.read_csv and have had no luck.

Here is my code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(
            os.path.join(wd,'Birthday_%s.csv' % datesuffix),
            encoding='utf-8')
pivot = pandas.pivot_table(df,
            index=['ClientID','ClientName','Branch'],
            values=['EmailAddress'],
            aggfunc='count',
            margins=True)
pivotlocation = os.path.join(wd,'BirthdayPivot.csv')
pivot.to_csv(pivotlocation)
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the line in question that is causing the issue.

```
ClientID | ClientName    | Branch        | Name     | EmailAddress
5555     | ExampleClient | ExampleBranch | Avendaño | email@email.com
```

It is the name column (containing 'Avendaño') that seems to be causing the issues.

Comment: Can you post the raw data just the first few lines, have you tried passing `encoding='utf-16'` also

Comment: I have tried using utf-16, but that did not work. I am unable to post any of the data, as it includes personal information of my company's clients.

Comment: You can provide random data, we just need data that reproduces the error, try to reduce the problem down to just the problem line

Comment: I added a sample of the data that is causing the issue.

Comment: Would it not be 'latin-1' rather than utf-8?

Comment: Thank you etna! That was it! First I have worked with csv files and panda, so I'm not too familiar with encoding types.

Comment: You're welcome, I've made a proper answer so you can mark the question as answered if you wish to do so ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper encoding may be 'latin-1' so you may want to consider:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(
            os.path.join(wd,'Birthday_%s.csv' % datesuffix),
            encoding='latin-1')
```