# convert xlsx file to csv using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using below code for `xlsx` to `csv` converstion

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\ABC.xlsx',ENCODING='utf-8')
read_file.to_csv (r'C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\ABC.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

The Code coverts the part till it reaches this special character in one of the column value

`Ñ` - Something like this

and it fails with below error

```
Error:- UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd1' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error handling ñ in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548411/error-handling-%c3%b1-in-pandas)

Comment: looking at above question , I tried using encoding='latin-1' but it did not help

Comment: What error do you see with `latin-1` ?